# How do I get CRA on Azure to behave correctly w.r.t. serviceWorker caching?

Tags: azure, caching, service-worker, create-react-app

I'm a little surprised that I can't find this answered already, but I've looked fairly hard. Apologies if I've missed it somewhere obvious.

---

TL;DR

**Question: How do I configure CRA (with SW) and the Azure App Service into which it is deployed, so that they play nicely together?**

---

There is a relatively well-discussed caching gotcha in the (current) default CreateReactApp config, relating to serviceWorkers.

It is lightly-discussed here, in the CRA docs: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#user-content-opting-out-of-caching (especially, points 5 & 6 from "Offline-First Considerations").

And an extended argument about its original inclusion in CRA can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2398

I'm not 100% certain of my understanding, so I'm going to start by summarising what I currently believe to be true:

---

- CRA has setup standard cache-busting processes in its main files.
- CRA has included a "Service Worker" pattern to do heavy-duty, ultra-sticky caching.
- The Service Worker can mostly load the page without even having an internet connection.
- In principle the SW will load the page, and then go and ask the server about the latest code.

  - If it detects a newer version, it will download that, and cache the new version.
  - It will *NOT* immediately display the new version, but would use the new version the **next** time the page is loaded, from its newly-updated cache.

All this is the standard, desired, intended behaviour of Service Workers.
But further to this:

- The serviceWorker is *NOT* cache busted.
- Depending on your host server configuration, the serviceWorker *itself* may get cached.

  - If that happens, then it will **permanently** display the stale version of the site, until the *serviceWorker* is cleared from the cache, and *then* it will start trying to update the available content.
- Default, out-of-the-box Azure configuration **does** cache the SW, and so far (after 24 hours) doesn't seem to release that cache at all :(

**Question 0: Have I got everything above correct, or am I missing something?**

---

I like the sound of the serviceWorker in general - it seems like it's doing a useful job, but it seems very unlikely that the CRA has provided something which when installed Out-of-box into Azure is fundamentally broken - the site I've deployed at the moment is (or gives the impression of being) impossible to push updates to!

I believe I know how to turn off the ServiceWorker, apparently including active steps required to purge it from people's browsers who have already seen it once and thus have an active SW already. (Though I don't understand clearly how that code will work!?) But I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it - I'd rather understand how to work *WITH* this feature, than how to *DISABLE* this feature.

So ...

**Question: How do I configure CRA (with SW) and the Azure App Service into which it is deployed, so that they play nicely together?**

Comment: I don't think you have to configure anything special on Azure for CRA and SW to work. You just have to make sure that there is no cache control on the service worker file so that the browser doesn't cache it. When you push a new version of the app, it will update the SW. The client will download and install this new SW that will download and update the app. But while this happens the old version of the app is displayed. So the client won't see a new version until the next navigation or refresh.

Comment: @J.Loscos "You have to make sure that there is no cache control" ... that sounds an awful lot like "configuring Azure" to me :D. Like I said, in the default set-up of Azure, the SW **IS** being cached. My question is specifically, how do I stop that!